# Samsung MultiWindowDecorSupportBridge resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android

[log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTZRJ.png)

```html
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue (ResourcesImpl.java:202)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getDimensionPixelSize (Resources.java:1536)
  at com.android.internal.policy.MultiWindowDecorSupport.initResources (MultiWindowDecorSupport.java:137)
  at com.android.internal.policy.MultiWindowDecorSupport.init (MultiWindowDecorSupport.java:132)
  at com.samsung.android.internal.policy.MultiWindowDecorSupportBridge.init (MultiWindowDecorSupportBridge.java:81)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.<init> (DecorView.java:319)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateDecor (PhoneWindow.java:2451)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor (PhoneWindow.java:2840)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView (PhoneWindow.java:429)
  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent (AlertController.java:255)
  at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate (AlertDialog.java:423)
  at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate (Dialog.java:759)
  at android.app.Dialog.show (Dialog.java:486)
  at com.qihoo.util.QHDialog$1.run (QHDialog.java:31)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
```

> I can only see the log in the GooglePlay console, but I do not know what is the specific reason for this problem. Who can help me, thank you!

Comment: Can you also post the code of your `QHDialog` class?